# Differentiate events in resource view in fullCalendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

Im using fullcalendar's scheduler to show different users schedule. Im also using background events as recurring events. 
In normal week view(not resource view) I have a code to differentiate background events on mouse click. If the event is not background type then a confirm dialog is prompted.  [image]
In the screenshot(Resource view), when I click on white event(3am -7am) confirm dialog is not prompted as its a background event.
When I click on grey section dialog is prompted(as expected). But when I click on grey section of (Test10 User10) between (3am-7am), confirm dialog is not prompted(should prompt), but is prompting when clicking on other time(besides 3am-7am) of Test10 User10. Its because 'clientEvents' is recognizing this section as background events of 'Saurav Dangol'(between 3am-7am).
All I want is a confirm dialog prompt(to differentiate) from background  events while coinciding with other users.Can anyone help? Thanks!

My code for differentiating background events.

```
var isValidEvent = function(start,end){
            return $("#eventCal").fullCalendar('clientEvents', function (event) {
                        return (event.rendering === "background" && 
                        (start.isAfter(event.start) || start.isSame(event.start,'minute')) &&
                        (end.isBefore(event.end) || end.isSame(event.end,'minute')));
                    }).length > 0;
        };
```

// Calendar code.

```
 var calendar = $('#eventCal').fullCalendar({
                header: {left: 'prev,next today', center: 'title', right: ''},
                selectable: true,
                defaultView: 'agendaDay',
                ignoreTimezone: true,
                allDayDefault: false,
                unselectAuto: false,
                editable: false,
                events: '${createLinkTo(dir: '/')}calendar/loadEvents/?userListMulti=' + ${userListMulti}[loopInt],
                resources: '${createLinkTo(dir: '/')}calendar/loadUsers/?userListMulti=' + ${userListMulti}[loopInt],
                eventRender: function (event, element) {
                    element.qtip({
                        content: event.title + "<br>" + moment(event.start).format('YYYY/MM/DD') + "<br>" + moment(event.start).format('HH:mm:ss') + "-" + moment(event.end).format('HH:mm:ss') + " " +
                        "${session.unsavedZone?calendar.userTimeZone(unsavedZone:session.unsavedZone):calendar.userTimeZone()}" + (event.member ? ("<br/>Member:" + event.member) : '')
                    });
                    element.find('.fc-time').html('');
                    element.find('.fc-title').append("<br/>" + moment(event.start).format('HH:mm:ss') + "-" + moment(event.end).format('HH:mm:ss') + " " +
                            "${session.unsavedZone?calendar.userTimeZone(unsavedZone:session.unsavedZone):calendar.userTimeZone()} " + (event.member ? ("<br/>Member:" + event.member) : ''));
                },
                viewRender: function(view, element){
                    $("#eventCal").addClass('agenda-week');
                },

                select:function (startDate, endDate, allDay) {
                        var currentView = $('#eventCal').fullCalendar('getView').name;
                        var confirmReady = false
                        var apppointmentReady = true

                        if(!isValidEvent(startDate,endDate)) {
                            apppointmentReady = false
                            if (confirm('You are about to add appointment during unavailable time. Are you sure?'))
                                confirmReady = true
                        }
                        if(apppointmentReady || confirmReady ){
                            $.fancybox({
                                titleShow:false,
                                width:400,
                                height:120,
                                autoDimensions:true,
                                overlayOpacity:0.6,
                                onComplete:function () {
                                    attachCalendarDatePickerClasses(startDate);
                                    $('#contactType').focus();
                                    $('#contactType').trigger("click");
                                    navigateCalendar = false;
                                },
                                onClosed:function(){
                                    navigateCalendar = true;
                                },
                                href:'${baseUrl}/calendar/loadForm/?clickedDate=' + moment(startDate).format('MM/DD/YYYY')+ '&calView=' + currentView + '&requestUser=' + $('#view_others').val()
                            });
                        }
                }
            });
```